# Exce­pti­on with th­re­ads in ­wp­f a­pp

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi guys I receive an exception `if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true || checkBox2.IsChecked == true)`:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

in my wpf app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    thr = new Thread[j];
    for (; i < j; i++)
    {
        thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
        thr[i].IsBackground = true;
        thr[i].Start();
    }
}

public void go()
{
    while (true)
    {
       string acc = "";
       string proxy = "";
       if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true || checkBox2.IsChecked == true)
       {
           if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
               Proxy.type = "http";
           else if (checkBox2.IsChecked == true)
               Proxy.type = "socks5";
           else
               Proxy.type = "none";
           proxy = rand_proxy();
       }
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: you can't access the checkbox control in a thread outside of the form.  You created a new thread and are using the checkbox in that new thread.  You can't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access UI elements from a thread other than one which was those created. Your check boxes are created on UI thread and you can access these only on UI thread.
try this.

```
public void go()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
        while (true)
        {
            string acc = "";
            string proxy = "";
            if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true || checkBox2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
                    Proxy.type = "http";
                else if (checkBox2.IsChecked == true)
                    Proxy.type = "socks5";
                else
                    Proxy.type = "none";
                proxy = rand_proxy();
            }
}), null);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark a post as an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access UI elements on a different thread than the UI. To work around this, you can check

```
checkBox1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()
```

and if true, use

```
checkBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke
```

or

```
checkBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

Comment: checkBox1.InvokeRequired, this is for Winform, not WPF

Answer (score 0):

Use [CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) to see if you need call [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) or Invoke
See also [this post](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2009/03/wpf-invokerequired-dispatchercheckacces.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're not allowed to access controls from threads other than the thread they were created on.  There's a good explanation of the WPF threading model [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx), and [this](http://nnish.com/2010/03/14/accessing-wpf-controls-on-a-non-ui-thread/) walks through the issue you are describing.

Good luck.